# How to convert exponent values in number in oracle

Tags: oracle

i am using oracle 11g.
I want to convert column value  4.74E-5 to 0.0000474.
Please help me with some suggestion how can i proceeds.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why your'e storing numbers in a string column? Don't do it unless it's just a temporary table

Comment: Do you actually have a string, or are you talking about how your client is displaying a number value by default?

Comment: No it's number column  only.but when I am rounding of small value showing as exponent. But I want value should show as it is. Exp 0.0000474.       I can change the client settings and it working as expected. But I am passing value to java side they want the value without exponent. Please suggest the way

Answer (score 3):

```
select to_number('4.74E-5', '9.99EEEE') n from dual;

         N
----------
  .0000474
```